# java test webhooks in a unit test way in integration tests

Tags: ssl, junit, jetty, webhooks, wiremock

We have a webhooks applications that only takes https as part of the callback URL. The application sends a POST request to the callback URL as a notification of some events. To be free of any 3rd party applications, we are trying to test the application using a mock/embedded web server behind the callback URL that is started by the integration test process.

However, after trying wiremock or jetty, it seems I cannot get around the SSL cert check from the webhooks application or client side, even though the callback URL can be set to https://127.0.0.1:someport :( The webhooks application we are testing resides in a different box than the one in which the integration tests are run.

Can someone please give me some hint/clue to solve this? Deeply appreciate it

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/viniciusffj/wiremock-http-requests-maker?

Answer (score 0):

thank you, a-kootstra, Actually it is not possible. I was confused. The webhooks applications lives on a separate server than the one from which tests are run. So the requests sent to localhost in our webhooks server will never reach the test server. I solved the problem by using AWS API gateway and DynamoDB. Worked perfectly. And no SSL certs issue either